# CustomControl Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have two custom controls, a and b,

Custom control`a` has a Dependency property of type `aClass`

Custom control `b`  has a set of `a` on it and has a Dependency property `List<aClass>` named `ItemSourceUI`

There is another class `bClass` that has on observable collection of type `aClass`, this is used on my view model.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyBClassInstance = new bClass();
    }

    private bClass _MyBClassInstance;
    public bClass MyBClassInstance
    {
        get { return _MyBClassInstance; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _MyBClassInstance, value); }
    }       

    ....
    // Here Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

This is my view

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UILib="clr-namespace:Gramas.UI;assembly=Gramas" x:Class="MyProy.Views.myView"
    Title="{Sample}" Height="600" Width="1200">
    <Grid>
        <UILIb:b Margin="10" ItemSourceUI="{Binding MyBClassInstance}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And at code behind constructor:

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

My problem is that Dependency property Setter of `ItemSourceUI` at `b` custom control never happen.

What I'm missing ?

**UPDATE:** This is the dependency property of `b`

```
    public bClass ItemSourceUI 
    {
        get { return (bClass)GetValue(ItemSourceUIProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemSourceUIProperty , value);
            DataContext = value;
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceUIProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSourceUI", typeof(bClass), typeof(b), new PropertyMetadata(default(bClass)));
```

Comment: What does '*Custom control b has a set of a on it*' mean? What is a 'set' of something? In fact, why are you even telling us about your `aClass`? I don't see that anywhere in your example code. Have you tried using an `ObservableCollection<aClass>` for your `ItemSourceUI` property instead of the `List<aClass>`

Comment: Sorry Sheridan, I'm trying to resume a Problem that actually is complex for me. Custom control ``b`` has 20 custom controls instances of type ``a`` on it, each instance need an ``aClass`` as a controlsource. But for now my first problem is that I can't get the ``ItemSourceUI`` at ``b``

Comment: Exactly... for now, your `aClass` is somewhat irrelevant to this current issue and maybe just confusing the matter. Can you please answer whether you tried using an ObservableCollection<aClass> for your ItemSourceUI property instead of the List<aClass>?

Comment: aClass elements Could change with user/program interaction, and i want to reflect those changes on UI. Thats why "I Think" i need an observable collection.

Comment: You forgot to show us the code how you defined that dependency property you talking about. What is the default value of it?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code causes all the issues you have. You screw up the DataContext and Binding needs proper DataContext in order to work.

```
public bClass ItemSourceUI 
{
    get { return (bClass)GetValue(ItemSourceUIProperty ); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ItemSourceUIProperty , value);
        DataContext = value;
    }
}
```

Remove that DataContext from setter and you should be fine.

If you have any questions about this feel free to ask :)

Comment: Because you destroy your own DataContext. Just remove that line and it will work. Ok?